# ValueChangeListener not firing for h:inputText when I have a converter as well for the inputText

Tags: jsf, converters, valuechangelistener

When I remove the f:convertDateTime , the valueChangeListerner is fired. if I put the converter it is not working . Also onblur is working better than onchange.

Can anyone tell me the fix.

Code snippet

```
<h:inputText id="EffectiveDate" styleClass="textInput" value="# 
{bbean.effectiveDate}" binding="#{bean.uiEffectiveDate}" 
onchange="submit();"
valueChangeListener="#{bbean.valueChangeEffectiveDate}">
<f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="#{bundle.datePattern}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Did you check for errors (validation errors or other). When you run you application in development mode, I'm 99% sure there is an error somewhere.

Comment: If I remove the ConvertDate it works , what does that indicate ?Is it because the Converter has an onblur or onchange event which is overriding the one I have put in InputText

Comment: And off-topic: `onchange="submit();"` is really, really old-school. JSF-1.1 or 1.2 project?

Comment: effectiveDate is java.util.Date. I have the JSF 2.1 jar but I can't move to xhtml at the moment as there are so many jsps to convert to xhtml.

Comment: The code above is not firing on onchange or onblur. It only fires when I click on submit button.